# set the iframe height automatically

Tags: html

I need to embed an HTML page inside a frame, and am using the following code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" style="width: 90%; height: 300px"
    scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"
    vspace="0" hspace="0">
```

I am trying to make the height set to auto so that the frame auto resizes to the page length without having to hardcode the height as I am doing here. I tried `height:auto` and `height:inherit` but it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried setting `height:100%` if the iframe is in the body that should make it fill the body?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this coding

```
<div>
    <iframe id='iframe2' src="Mypage.aspx" frameborder="0" style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%;
        width: 100%; position: absolute;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: I've found using the style height and width is glitchy. The height and width attributes are the important thing here that seems to work consistently. Is there a reason you used both?

Comment: % on iframe's height/width is invalid HTML5 as per spec (it was valid before though)

Answer (score 12):

Solomon's answer about bootstrap inspired me to add the CSS the bootstrap solution uses, which works really well for me.

```
.iframe-embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
.iframe-embed-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.iframe-embed-responsive-16by9 {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}
<div class="iframe-embed-wrapper iframe-embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="iframe-embed" src="vid.mp4"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! I had to get rid of the `height: 0;` but aside from that it works flawlessly, and this is with an angular page in an iframe hosted in a resizable modal popup in old gwt app!

Comment: Works on current Chrome Sep 2020. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you a framework like Bootstrap you can make any iframe video responsive by using this snippet:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="vid.mp4" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the sites are on separate domains, the calling page can't access the height of the iframe due to cross-browser domain restrictions. If you have access to both sites, you may be able to use the [document domain hack](http://adam.kahtava.com/journal/2010/03/18/the-same-origin-policy-jsonp-vs-the-documentdomain-property/). Then anroesti's links should help.

Comment: This library on GitHub solves the cross-domain problem, along with making sure the iFrame stays sized to the content when things change.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer