# Is there a way to tell an iframe to be of the exact width and height of the page it contains using CSS only?

Tags: html, css, iframe

Let's suppose I have an `iframe` and it loads a page by a URL. Is it possible to make sure its `width` and `height` will be of the exact size of the page it contains upon loading it using CSS only?

Comment: Are you asking how to make the iframe fill the page? Otherwise, what do you mean by "exact size of the page it contains"?

Comment: No, the question is about Page1 loading Page2 through an iframe and I wish to make sure the size of the iframe will match the size of Page2 which will be loaded inside it. So, I wish to make sure that no scroll bars are needed inside the iframe, for example.

Comment: There are several dupes to your question, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/819416/5743988), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9975810/5743988), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15255858/5743988), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24157940/5743988). What have you tried?

Comment: The first allows Javascript solutions

Comment: The second allow Javascript solutions as well

Comment: The third question is about displaying an iframe in 100% of the page's width and height. None of the three dupes were actual dupes.

Comment: As about the things I have tried: I absolutely do not know how should this be done, therefore I have searched for CSS solutions. Since I did not find any, I concluded that this is worth to be asked as a question.

Comment: The closest one I've found is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24157940/5743988). Considering there are no accepted or upvoted answers, and it's been viewed 25k times, I don't think this is possible.

Comment: @4castle, you are probably right, but let's leave this question opened for a while. If there is no info about it, then I will try to research the matter more deeply. There is a Javascript solution though, but that will not work if Javascript is switched off, so, as far as I know, there is no bullet-proof solutions for this, but I might be wrong.